# How to configure logstash to transfer data from MS-SQL server to elasticsearch

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, amazon-rds

I am trying to copy my table data from MSSQL server to elasticsearch, after going through some documents i wrote my config file for logstash, when i run the file from command prompt , i get this message :

> "J_3a_.ELK.logstash_minus_6_dot_6_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline.block
>   in start_input"
>   [image: screenshot from the command line]
>   I have the MSSQL database in aws-RDS.

This is my conf file

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_driver_library => "J:\Java\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
        jdbc_connection_string => 
       "jdbc:sqlserver://skunestdevdb.czdnys4mper2.ap-southeast- 
         2.rds.amazonaws.com;database=skudevusr;user= 
       <my_username>;password=<my_password>"
        jdbc_user => "<my_username>"
        jdbc_password => "<myPassword>#"
        statement => "select * from product"
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch{
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => ["skunest_qa"]
    }
}
```

I cant seem to get what is wrong here, i have provided necessary details in the conf file, the command line stucks showing above message. I have tried removing the username and password from the connection string.
Help!!

Comment: You shouldn't provide username and password in jdbc connectron string when you additionally provide fields `jdbc_user` and `jdbc_password`. Can you also start Logsatsh in debug mode `--debug` and then send logs?

Comment: @MichaelDz i removed the username and password from the connection string and it still result in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
input {  
jdbc {
    # SqlServer jdbc connection string to your database, productdb
    #  "jdbc:sqlserver://HostName\instanceName;database=DBName;user=UserName;password=Password" 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLExpress;database=productdb;user=sa;password=test@123"
    # The user you want to execute your statement as
    jdbc_user => nil
    # The path to your downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:/Program Files/sqljdbc_6.0/enu/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar"
    # The name of the driver class for SqlServer
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    # Query for testing purpose
    statement => "SELECT * from product"
}
}
output {  
    elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
     index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
 }

   }
```

Comment: Can I put multiple SQL statements here? if yes, then how?